# Probar funciones asíncronas en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, callback, async

Tengo esta prueba unitaria para un código de codewars:

```
describe("Solution", function() {
    it("should test for something", function(done) {
        get_member_since('Javatlacati', async function(result) {
            Test.assertEquals(result, "Apr 2014", "Wrong year");
            done();
        });
        get_member_since('smile67', async function(result) {
            Test.assertEquals(result, 'Sep 2015', "Wrong year");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

funcionaba en versiones anteriores de node, pero ahora me arroja lo siguiente contra la `versión 8.1.3`:

> (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: done is not a function
>
> (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>
> (node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>
> (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: done is not a function

por si fuera relevante el método que estoy probando tiene esta firma:

```
async function get_member_since(username,callback) {
```

¿Existe otra forma de probarlo usando esencialmente solo [mocha](/questions/tagged/mocha) y [chai](/questions/tagged/chai) (sin usar jest porque su contenedor creo que no lo tiene agregado)?

Comment: como estas corriendo el script? puedes incluirlo en tu pregunta?

Comment: La forma de correrlo es en codewars... Sinceramente no sé como lo tengan configurado. Yo para mis pruebas locales por lo general lo corro directamente con una tarea de npm porque no sé mucho, y en este punto no recuerdo como lo intenté correr.

Comment: Deberías mostrar la implementación de `get_member_since` porque parece que tiene más de una inconsistencia...

Comment: Por una parte es `async` por lo que devuelve una `Promise` pero el resultado se obtiene a través de una *callback*... Se están mezclando conceptos.

Answer (score 0):

veo que en el segundo get_member_since, estas pasandole result como atributo, pero resuelves con done(), lo que le debes cambiar result por done, también que estas usando promesas así que al no poner await en get_member_since (asumiendo que son asíncronas) el código se pierde, pero esto ultimo puedo estar equivocado, te dejare las 2 versiones que puedo concluir deberían funcionar. por ultimo también me fije que tienes 2 done en un solo it, lo ideal es que tengas 1 solo done por it

1.- solo cambiando result por done y separando en 2 it

```
describe("Solution", function() {
    it("should test for something", function(done) {
        get_member_since('Javatlacati', async function(result) {
            Test.assertEquals(result, "Apr 2014", "Wrong year");
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should test for something", function(done) {
        get_member_since('smile67', async function(result) {
            Test.assertEquals(result, 'Sep 2015', "Wrong year");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

2.- cambiando result por done y agregando awaits y separando en 2 it

```
describe("Solution",async function() {
    it("should test for something", async function(done) {
        await get_member_since('Javatlacati', async function(result) {
            Test.assertEquals(result, "Apr 2014", "Wrong year");
            done();
        });
    });
    it("should test for something 2", async function(done) {

        await get_member_since('smile67', async function(done) {
            Test.assertEquals(result, 'Sep 2015', "Wrong year");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```