# Simular la carga asíncrona de contenido en javascript

Tags: javascript, async, async-await

quiero simular como sería llamar a una aplicación o servicio que obtuviera contenido a usar en una función de mi sistema.

Para meterlos un poco en contexto, me estoy imaginando una aplicación, sistema o servicio que nos de una cita famosa, poema horóscopo o lo que se les venga a la mente, y quiero obtener la cadena de esa cita de manera asíncrona.

Esto es lo que he intentado

```js
async function obtenerCitaFamosa() {
  let quote;
  // esto simularía una llamada a un sistema externo
  await setTimeout(function() {
    quote = "Walter tianguis dice que mañana te vas a morir prro >:V aaaaa te creas dice que eres bien chido";
  }, 100)
  return quote || 'nu ma no se pudo cargar :\'v';
}

async function imprimeCitaFamosa() {
  try {
    var quote = await obtenerCitaFamosa();
    console.log(quote);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
console.log(obtenerCitaFamosa());
imprimeCitaFamosa();
```

como pueden ver al correrlo se obtiene únicamente el mensaje para los casos en de error siempre.
¿De qué forma se puede modificar para que me dé el resultado esperado?

#### Otros intentos fallidos

```js
function sistemaExterno(quote, done) {
  quote = "Walter tianguis dice que mañana te vas a morir prro >:V aaaaa te creas dice que eres bien chido";
  console.log(`valor de cita cambiado a ${quote}`);
  done();
}

async function obtenerCitaFamosa() {
  let quote = 'nu ma no se pudo cargar :\'v';
  // esto simularía una llamada a un sistema externo
  await (setTimeout(sistemaExterno(quote, () => {
    console.log('soy el callback soy el callback soy el callback soy el callback !')
  }), 100))
  return quote;
}

async function imprimeCitaFamosa() {
  try {
    var quote = await obtenerCitaFamosa();
    console.log(`La cita del día es: ${quote}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
console.log(obtenerCitaFamosa());
imprimeCitaFamosa();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con una promesa, de la siguiente manera:

```js
function obtenerCitaFamosa() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let quote;
    try {
      setTimeout(function() {
        quote = "Walter tianguis dice que mañana te vas a morir prro >:V aaaaa te creas dice que eres bien chido";
        resolve(quote);
      }, 100);
    } catch (error) {
      reject('nu ma no se pudo cargar :\'v');
    }

  });
}

async function imprimeCitaFamosa() {
  try {
    var quote = await obtenerCitaFamosa();
    console.log(quote);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

imprimeCitaFamosa();
```

No necesario usar `async` en la función `obtenerCitaFamosa` ya que no se ésta usando `await` dentro de ella.

Comment: Ya le puse el resto del código papu para que vean que no nada más eres guaguara

Comment: igual si tienes tiempo, tengo [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/281543/probar-funciones-as%c3%adncronas-en-javascript) que estoy intentando de pruebas asincrónicas

Answer (score 2):

Una buena solución fue la que dio @Arnuelgm. Una alternativa si es que deseas mantener async await, podrías realizar algo como esto:

```js
async function obtenerCitaFamosa() {

  const espera = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function() {
    msj = "Walter tianguis dice que mañana te vas a morir prro >:V aaaaa te creas dice que eres bien chido";
    resolve(msj);
  }, ms));

  let respuesta = await espera(3000);

  return respuesta || 'nu ma no se pudo cargar :\'v';
}
async function imprimeCitaFamosa() {
  try {
    var quote = await obtenerCitaFamosa();
    console.log(quote);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

imprimeCitaFamosa();
```